# How to Spring Security handle all modules in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I using Spring and Spring Security in my project. I using microservice architecture.

**My project looks like:**

1. Module

   - Controller 1, some class and jpa
2. Module 2

   - Controller 2, some class and config security (jwt,outh2 and some role...). Dependency spring security in here,

When I build module 2, Spring Security work ok. It handle all request in controller 2, filter using `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and generator token. But when I build module 1 and call some API in controller 1 maybe spring security not work. It always allow request, can't generator token 
I have a question.

I want config security in module 2 and want it to handle controller module 1? Is it possible? Or some way how to only config spring security in one module and using it all project (all modules).

Comment: If you would like to secure multiple services (deployed to the different app servers) with a common security provider, you should use Single Sign-On approach.

Comment: @trungtbdn11 did my answer work, or do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

Your last suggestion is how I'd go about it. I'd add another module to my project, and include spring-security (and related configuration) as a dependency to that module:

```
─── parent
    ├── module1
    ├── module2
    └── security-module
```

In your `security-module` you could have all your security related configuration, including spring-security dependency, and your `module1` and `module2` had dependencies to `security-module`.

Comment: Try your answer but I'm getting a 401 on modules that include the security-module module. Authentication in the security module works correctly using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Any suggestion?