# Why Spring Security throws 401 when placed in a different module?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-security, multi-module

I'm trying to create a **Gradle multi-module** project following the *hexagonal architecture*.

Currently, my project looks like this when executing `./gradlew -q projects`:

[image]

All is working except for **Spring Security**, my idea was to keep all Spring Security configurations in a **different module**.

But when keeping the **WebSecurityConfiguration** in a module that is **not** the **BOOT module** (*which is the one that contains the actual main class*), it throws **401** always.

***This is the summary:***

1. When WebSecurityConfiguration class stays in the BOOT module it works like a charm ✅

[image: This works!]

2. When WebSecurityConfiguration is moved to a different module all rest calls to the controllers return 401 ❌

[image: This doesn't work...]

***Things to keep in mind:***

1. Application.yaml is ok since the application works with spring security when option 1.
2. WebSecurityConfiguration code is ok since the application works with spring security when option 1.
3. See this thread and the **comment** on the answer, I'm facing the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656278
4. All modules **except BOOT** are configured with `jarEnabled = true`, so they are not bootable.

Any help will be welcomed because I am going crazy with this.

Comment: I guess, scanning for beans and configurations is the problem. Show the package where the main application lives, and the packages of your beans and configurations, especially your security config class.

Comment: Add  "@Import(YourSecurityConfig.class)" to your main class & try.

Comment: Well ... a better suggestion would be to put the main application class into a package that is a parent of all other packages in the whole project.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you are the best!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH, I will post an answer with your comment, you saved me so much time and sanity.